# WPF ListView items drawn

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Listview with templated items (which looked just like Windows Explorer). My problem is when I openning folder which contains a whole lot of files that ListView loads those files not  smoothly.(see video: http://screencast.com/t/bY7ucELj9I).

Does someone has any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to virtualize your ListView's Items. Example

```
     <ListView Name="ListViewWithVirtualization" Height="100" Margin="5"
     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

If you set VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = “Recycling” then each container will get reuse instead of destroy. You will get better performance by specifying VirtualizationMode to Recycling than basic default virtualization. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx